# how to make whole menu bar item + area clickable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have one menu bar. I just found something useful thing to make whole menu bar area should be clickable with jquery.

here is design code :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MenuControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MenuControl"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Menu3.css" type="text/css" />
<div id="header" align="center" >
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                 
     $(".Menu").click(function(e) {
         window.location = $(e.target).find("a").attr("href");
         return false;
     });
});
</script>
<table width="100%" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
   <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation ="Horizontal" CssClass="Menu"
        ForeColor ="Black" Width="100%" ScrollDownText="" 
        StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/images/down_arrow_1.gif">
     <StaticMenuItemStyle Height="40px"/>
     <DynamicMenuItemStyle Height="40px" CssClass="Menu" HorizontalPadding="10px"/>
     <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menuhover" />
     <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuhover" />
    </asp:Menu>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

how ever this works fine when i click area of menu item but when i clicks original menu item then error occurs like:

```
Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /EasyWeb/undefined


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

Is there problem with my jquery code??

**------------------------------------Updated-----------------------------------------**

here is html full markup:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
   <a href="#menu1_Menu1_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=uS7YYfXnUXiSaHkS-NobyQ2&amp;t=635234834251287338" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><table id="menu1_Menu1" class="Menu menu1_Menu1_2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n0"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td style="width:3px;"></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n1"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="Register.aspx">Sign Up</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td style="width:3px;"></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n2"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services')">Services</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="images/down_arrow_1.gif" alt="Expand Services" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n3"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Tools')">Tools</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="images/down_arrow_1.gif" alt="Expand Tools" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n4"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links')">Important Links</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="images/down_arrow_1.gif" alt="Expand Important Links" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n5"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Acts')">Acts</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="images/down_arrow_1.gif" alt="Expand Acts" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n6"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Rules')">Rules</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="images/down_arrow_1.gif" alt="Expand Rules" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n7"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/DIT/Circulars.aspx">Circulars</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td style="width:3px;"></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n8"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/DIT/Notifications.aspx">Notification</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td style="width:3px;"></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n9"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/allforms.asp">Forms</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td><td style="width:3px;"></td><td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n10"><table class="menu1_Menu1_4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 menu1_Menu1_3" href="http://easyweb999.wordpress.com/">Blog</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table><div id="menu1_Menu1n2Items" class="menu1_Menu1_0">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n11">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Corporate Services')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Corporate Services</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n12">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Corporate Finance')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Corporate Finance</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n13">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Corporate Finance')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Corporate Finance</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n14">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Accounting Services')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Accounting Services</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n15">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Payroll')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Payroll</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n16">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Benefits of Outsourcing')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Benefits of Outsourcing</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n17">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Income Tax')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Income Tax</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n18">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Value Added Tax (VAT)')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Value Added Tax (VAT)</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n19">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\Service Tax')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Service Tax</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n20">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Services\\TDS/FBT')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">TDS/FBT</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n2ItemsUp" onmouseover="PopOut_Up(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=WOcqFGSOX-4KCNzzZKFmZljtQUM9O7kD3Xq3fcz3ZVY1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Scroll up" />
    </div><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n2ItemsDn" onmouseover="PopOut_Down(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=-r2DsOX_bJ0J6gpZu3I-GAcZkKhJPqAevVJdTAHh6E01&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="" />
    </div>
</div><div id="menu1_Menu1n3Items" class="menu1_Menu1_0">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n21">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Tools\\TDS Rates for N.R.I u/s 195')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">TDS Rates for N.R.I u/s 195</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n22">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Tools\\Rates of Income Tax')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Rates of Income Tax</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n23">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Tools\\Rates of NSC Interest')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Rates of NSC Interest</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n24">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Tools\\ROC Fee Structure')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">ROC Fee Structure</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n3ItemsUp" onmouseover="PopOut_Up(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=WOcqFGSOX-4KCNzzZKFmZljtQUM9O7kD3Xq3fcz3ZVY1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Scroll up" />
    </div><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n3ItemsDn" onmouseover="PopOut_Down(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=-r2DsOX_bJ0J6gpZu3I-GAcZkKhJPqAevVJdTAHh6E01&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="" />
    </div>
</div><div id="menu1_Menu1n4Items" class="menu1_Menu1_0">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n25">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\PAN')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">PAN</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand PAN" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n26">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\TAN')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">TAN</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand TAN" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n27">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\E-Payment Online')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">E-Payment Online</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand E-Payment Online" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n28">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\IncomeTax')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">IncomeTax</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand IncomeTax" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n29">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\CBEC')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">CBEC</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand CBEC" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n30">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\PF &amp; ESI')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">PF & ESI</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand PF &amp; ESI" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n31">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\Excise and Service Tax')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Excise and Service Tax</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand Excise and Service Tax" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n32">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\MCA')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">MCA</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand MCA" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n33">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\VAT')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">VAT</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n34">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\CA/CS/CWA')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">CA/CS/CWA</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand CA/CS/CWA" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n35">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\CIBIL')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">CIBIL</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand CIBIL" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n36">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\IEPF')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">IEPF</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=h5TZ_gXVB1RnNj7NTVeAgYjX6yi42JGwgXdtAbGcijc1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Expand IEPF" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n37">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('menu1$Menu1','Important Links\\RTI')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">RTI</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n4ItemsUp" onmouseover="PopOut_Up(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=WOcqFGSOX-4KCNzzZKFmZljtQUM9O7kD3Xq3fcz3ZVY1&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="Scroll up" />
    </div><div class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6 menu1_Menu1_0" id="menu1_Menu1n4ItemsDn" onmouseover="PopOut_Down(this)" onmouseout="PopOut_Stop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="/EasyWeb/WebResource.axd?d=-r2DsOX_bJ0J6gpZu3I-GAcZkKhJPqAevVJdTAHh6E01&amp;t=635234834251287338" alt="" />
    </div>
</div><div id="menu1_Menu1n25Items" class="menu1_Menu1_0">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n38">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/Services/KnowYourPanLink.html" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Know Your PAN</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n39">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="https://tin.tin.nsdl.com/tan/StatusTrack.html" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Status Of Pan NSDL</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n40">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="http://www.myutiitsl.com/PANONLINE/panTracker.do" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Status Of Pan UTIITSL</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n41">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="https://tin.tin.nsdl.com/pan/index.html" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Apply Online Pan NSDL</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n42">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="http://www.utiitsl.com/" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Apply Online Pan UTIITSL</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr><tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="menu1_Menu1n43">
            <td><table class="Menu menu1_Menu1_6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="menu1_Menu1_1 Menu menu1_Menu1_5" href="http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/DITTaxmann/IncomeTaxRules/pdf/Form49aE.PDF" target="_blank" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Form Apply For PAN</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

.........

Comment: By the looks of things you're showing us the `.net (asp)` files please could you show the actually outputting html markup?

Comment: ok view source that out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
window.location = $(e.target).find("a").attr("href");
```

When you click the `a` element, then `e.target` becomes the `a` element itself, and so...

```
$(e.target).find('a');
```

returns an empty jQuery object, because `e.target` has not child elements. You need to do this, if you want to use e.target:

```
var $a = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a' ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).find('a');
window.location = $a.attr('href');
```

This way you check whether you've already clicked in the `a` element. If it is, uses it; if not, searches for it.

Comment: Did you try it? In any case, I changed the solution, but the other one was more elegant.